# Add Tkinter in the project on Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have written application on Python (version 3) that uses Tkinter. However it was found computers in my university have python 3.4 without Tkinter and I have not permission to install it.

Can I add to a project tkinter to use it on these computers?

Comment: Try `import tkinter` and not `import Tkinter`

Comment: I've tried. Unsuccessfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also try this.  Python comes with Tkinter installed, but it is possible the university compiles their own custom version.

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as tk     ## Python 2.x
else:
    import tkinter as tk     ## Python 3.x
print("version", tk.TclVersion)
```

Comment: It helped to find solution. Thank you.